# Should we allow grace period to confirm email address?

Tags: security, email-verification

1. A user registered with an email address on the website platform.
2. A confirmation email is sent to the user.
3. The user is redirected to the dashboard, but the user is not allowed to access private information on the website platform.
4. User logs out.
5. Currently, if the user does not confirm email address within 48 hours, their account will become inactive, and they won't be allowed to login until they confirm their email address.

Should this grace period of 48 hours be given to the user, or not allow them to access the website platform until they have confirmed their email address?

Is it advisable to allow this grace period to the users to confirm their email addresses? Are there any security concerns if we allow grace period?

Comment: I think this is a business decision and depends on a few factors. Do you have compliance requirements? What will happen if a user with a fake email address has access? Where does 48 hours come from, does it make a difference if it's 0 hours (no grace time), 1 hour, 1 week or 1 year? So I think the answer to your question fully depends on your business scenario. (Also note that these are rethorical questions. :) These are the sort of questions that you have to go through to get to your specific answer to the question.)

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."*